# Is it just me, or do answers with the most votes now show up on the BOTTOM?

Tags: discussion, answers, up-votes

The question is in the title... did this change recently, or am I hallucinating?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it hasn't changed. Head to the three tabs right below the question on the right side. `---------^`

Ensure that the **votes** tab is clicked. This will order the answers by votes.